Structural Vector Autoregression (SVAR) in Python - Problem with formulating and understanding the code
I have a research question where the aim in to see how Housing Index is affected by a Central Banks purchases of covered bonds. My data consists of, Housing Index, Policy rate, Mortgage rates, Covered Bonds, Household Debt-to-GDP ratio and Inflation.
I planned to do the analysis in the following order and have finished only step 1-4.

Akaike Information Criterion (selection lag - chose 1)
Augmented Dickey Fuller test (test for stationary - did not have stationary in any variable except covered bonds)
Johansen Cointegration test - Test for cointegration since the variables were not stationary
Vector Error Correction Model - Since there was cointegration
Structural Vector Autoregression Model - I really don't understand why I am supposed to this
Impulse Response Function - I understand this part but haven't come this far
Forecast Error Variance Decomposition

Is there anyone that can help me understand and formulate code for step 4-5? I have some code that I have been running but cannot sense-check it, and really don't understand the why's and don'ts.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
